# How to trigger in input button?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

i have a input button in a form:

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="hidde" name="free"  id="helpdiv" onmouseover="this.style.background='url('../images/thank_you/thank.png');'" onmouseout="this.style.background='url('../images/thank_you/thank_you.png');'" style="width: 236px; height: 127px;">
```

and a jQuery script that has an event:

```
onlike:function(response){
    $('.uncontent').hide('fade');
    $('input#helpdiv').trigger('click');
}
```

when that function triggers i would like the input button to be triggered as well. 
the function is working because `$('.uncontent').hide('fade');` gets triggered

any ideas?

**Edit:**

`$('input#helpdiv').trigger('click')`
or

`$('input#helpdiv').click()`

won't work for some reason

Comment: Why are you using the selector `$(input#helpdiv)`? Why not just use the id since it should be unique, i.e. `$('#helpdiv')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
$('#helpdiv').click();
```

If you're trying to submit a form via this button select the `<form>` element and call submit() on it like so....

```
$('#helpdiv').parents('form').eq(0).submit();
```

Comment: +1 - not sure who downvoted you but you have a solid point about submitting the form via `submit()` instead of simply emulating a submit button click.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is fine. You have some funky quotes going on in your mouseover events. This is why we should avoid doing that.

```
id="helpdiv" onmouseover="this.style.background='url('../images/thank_you/thank.png');'"
```

See the `background='url('..` ?

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="" class="hidde" name="free" id="helpdiv" style="width: 236px; height: 127px;" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#helpdiv').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image','url("../images/thank_you/thank.png")');
},function(){
    $(this).css('background-image','url("../images/thank_you/thank_you.png")');
});

// Test it
$('#helpdiv').click(function(){
    alert('helpdiv clicked');
});
```

Next step would be to abstract your CSS as well ;)